# How to allow a fullwidth character as part of a username in ipython

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, ipython, chinese-locale

I am having the following issue loading `ipython` with a Chinese language OS X machine:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ May$ ipython
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fff795d9300 (most recent call first):
/Users/Ｍay/anaconda/bin/python.app: line 3:  1860 Abort trap: 6           /Users/Ｍay/anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

I have been able to circumvent this problem installing anaconda into the root directory and then running ipython (i.e. ipython from '//anaconda/bin/ipython').

For now, this works, but I would prefer to install anaconda into the user location eventually. I suspect that the issue might have to do with a character used in the username itself `May` with a fullwidth M (compare to `May`).

Is there a way to install anaconda or to start ipython to accommodate this username (if the username is in fact the problem)?

EDIT: To clarify, this issue still occurs after changing the locale back to English (LANG gives `en_US.UTF-8`).